SQL result used in same SQL
I have one table



cp_id
id
value




112
5
ok


3369
112
ok


10
8
ok


3368
10
ok



and I am struggling with, if I want information for id '5' (i got only one row)
SELECT *  FROM table WHERE id= '5'

but I need to find out the related information as well.
result, which I want:



cp_id
id
value




112
5
ok


3369
112
ok



I tried:
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE cp_id = (SELECT cp_id FROM table where id = 5)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = 5

but it's not correct

Shouldn't that be WHERE id IN (SELECT cp_id FROM table where id = 5)

@Charlieface ahh yes, you're right a only one qstn yet... is it possible another way? Because for example - i want mark  for each row, what root id (in this case is root id is 5, but if i will have a lot of results, it would be nice to have mark each row for which root ID it is.)

Use a join maybe?

You mean you want the hierarchy and it might be more than one level deep? If so it also depends on what backend you are using. You didn't tag your backend.

You could use Cross Join Lateral to connect matching root ID rows and  filter the result using inner join:
WITH    -- S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl ( CP_ID, ID, VALUE ) AS
        ( Select  112,   5,  'ok'  From Dual Union ALl 
          Select 3369, 112,  'ok'  From Dual Union ALl 
          Select   20,   8,  'ok'  From Dual Union ALl 
          Select 3368,   10, 'ok'  From Dual 
        )

--      S Q L :
Select    t.*
From      tbl t
Inner Join ( Select     t.CP_ID, t1.CP_ID "CP_ID_2"
              From    tbl t
              Cross Join Lateral ( Select * From tbl Where ID = t.CP_ID ) t1
           ) t1 ON( t.CP_ID IN(t1.CP_ID, t1.CP_ID_2) )

/*    R e s u l t :
     CP_ID         ID VA
---------- ---------- --
       112          5 ok
      3369        112 ok    */


I believe you mean to get hierarchical data and it might be more than one level deep. Code depends on the backend and generally is done with recursive CTEs. ie:
in SQL Server:
WITH cte (CP_ID, ID, VALUE) AS (
  SELECT CP_ID, ID, VALUE from myTable 
  where ID = 5
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.CP_ID, t.ID, t.VALUE from myTable t
  inner join cte on cte.CP_ID = t.ID
)
SELECT CP_ID, ID, VALUE FROM cte;

DBFddile demo for SQL server
In postgreSQL:
WITH RECURSIVE cte (CP_ID, ID, VALUE) AS (
  SELECT CP_ID, ID, VALUE from myTable 
  where ID = 5
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.CP_ID, t.ID, t.VALUE from myTable t
  inner join cte on cte.CP_ID = t.ID
)
SELECT CP_ID, ID, VALUE FROM cte;

DBFiddle demo for postgreSQL

Is it possible use in Databricks ?

@Cesc, I don't know what databricks is.
